# ¿Se puede graficar en tiempo real en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

He estado tratando de obtener una gráfica en tiempo real con matplotlib pero se me ha hecho casi imposible, ¿existe alguna forma de poder realizar esto?

La cuestión es que estoy recibiendo datos mediante el puerto usb y los voy almacenando en una lista,la cual cada vez es mayor ya que hay datos nuevos. Lo que quiero es que a medida que se vaya recibiendo un nuevo dato(lo cual es muy muy rápido) se vaya mostrando en una gráfica en tiempo real.

Intenté así pero no funcionó:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import analog

b = analog('COM3')
g = []

while (True):
    val = b.analogRead(pin)
    res = int((int(val) * 250000) / 1023)
    g.append(res)
    print("%s ............... %s" % (res, t))
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(g)
    plt.show(block = False)

plt.close('all')
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo has estado tratando de hacerlo? Tal vez se más fácil ayudarte si muestras lo que has avanzado con tu código

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo en matplotlib o con opciones más ligeras como PyQwt. Como comenta @Elenasys, comparte algo de código para comprender mejor lo que estás intentando hacer y te intentaremos ayudar.

Comment: debido a que los while son muy rápido pensé que si abría un plot y lo cerraba de una iba a ser imperceptible para el ojo humano jejeje, pero no 
funcionó.. intenté hacer así.


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import analog

b = analog('COM3')

g = []

while (True):
  
        val = b.analogRead(pin)
        res = int((int(val)*250000)/1023)
        g.append(res)
        print("%s ............... %s"%(res, t))
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(g)
        plt.show(block = False)
        plt.close('all')

Comment: Hola @MichaelLan, he incluido el código en la pregunta - revisa si es correcto (puedes editarlo tú también), con esto creo que se puede reabrir la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, aca hay un ejemplo https://github.com/eyllanesc/S2DSEF/blob/master/pc/v2.0/Communication, leí el dispositivo bluetooth a traves de un puerto serie, que es similar a lo que tu deseas, como observación.

Answer (score 5):

Lo siguiente debería funcionar aunque no tiene porqué tener un gran rendimiento. Si vas a hacer un gráfico cada segundo te vale, si necesitas algo que dibuje más gráficas por segundo se puede mirar de optimizar este código (pero se hará un poco más complejo) o se puede usar PyQwt. El código simple en matplotlib sería:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion() # decimos de forma explícita que sea interactivo

y = [] # los datos que vamos a dibujar y a actualizar

# el bucle infinito que irá dibujando
while True:
    y.append(np.random.randn(1)) # añadimos un valor aleatorio a la lista 'y'

    # Estas condiciones las he incluido solo para dibujar los últimos 
    # 10 datos de la lista 'y' ya que quiero que en el gráfico se 
    # vea la evolución de los últimos datos
    if len(y) <= 10:
        plt.plot(y)
    else:
        plt.plot(y[-10:])

    plt.pause(0.05) # esto pausará el gráfico
    plt.cla() # esto limpia la información del axis (el área blanca donde
              # se pintan las cosas.
```

Comment: ¿SE PUEDE AGREGAR UN NOMBRE AL COSTADO DE LAS GRAFICAS?

Answer (score -1):

Otra opción interesante es [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) que está escrita en Python y utiliza PyQt4/PySide para la parte gráfica y NumPy para el cálculo.

Algo que me sorprendió es que puedes [interactuar con el gráfico](http://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/develop/mouse_interaction.html) en tiempo real con el ratón (incluso con [gráficos en 3D](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/images/pyqtgraph-3d.png)).